# JBPM - Cloud Foundry Support

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, cloud-foundry, jbpm

I have a workflow process developed using JBPM PDL. I am evaluating options for deploying this process archive either in a tomcat environment hosted independently or integrate this with springboot and deploy / scale in a PAAS platform like Pivotal Cloud foundry.

Can JBPM process archives be integrated with springboot and deployed in pivotal cloud foundry platform?

Comment: Were you able to use jBPM in PCF? If Yes, would you be able to educate us?

Comment: @Divs , sorry , I didn't end up doing that. However you may have come across this link - http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-jbpm/jbpm6/building-a-jbpm6-application-with-springboot